# Validate Presence Of At Least One of Several

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, model

I have an ActiveRecord model with the following three attributes:

```
data_1
data_2
data_3
```

How do I write a validation that checks whether at least one of those fields is *not* `blank?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Here is how I did it

```
validate :has_content


def has_content
  if data_1.blank? && data_2.blank? && data_3.blank?
    errors[:base] = "Must have a filename or a URL"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with custom validator like this,

in your model write,

```
 validates :validate_attrlist

 def validate_attrlist
    unless !data_1.blank? or !data_2.blank? or !data_3.blank?
       record.errors[:base] << "Can't be blank"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is actually incorrect. I asked for a validation that checks: 'at least one of those fields is not blank?' but this validates if *any* fields are blank. It should be 'if data_1.blank? and data_2.blank? and data_3.blank? shouldn't it?

Comment: you mean, none of the field need to be blank? It will raise error if none of the field is blank. Isn't this your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the list of attributes and the collection #any? #all? methods:

`[attr1, attr2, ..., attrN].all? {|a| a.nil? || a == "" }`

`[attr1, attr2, ..., attrN].map(&:to_s).any? {|a| !a.empty? }`

This is plain Ruby, ActiveSupport it's even easier, you have #present? or #blank?, e.g.:

`[attr1, attr2, ..., attrN].any?(&:present?)`

Last, for two values you can use XOR operation:  `value1 ^ value2`